# Application.OnKey to start macro with a variable as parameter

Tags: excel, vba

Every key pressed a-z A-Z 0-9 starts a macro called LetterPress with the key pressed as a parameter.
Basically I have an Application.OnKey for every key a-z A-Z 0-9

If the active cell is a certain cell I want to start a sub, else I just want to send the key like normal. That starts a recursive loop that doesn't end. So here is what I'm trying:

```
Sub LetterPress(B as String)
If Application.ActiveCell.Row = 3 And Application.ActiveCell.Column = 5 And Application.ActiveSheet.Name = "Search" And Not IsNumeric(B) Then
    Call Search1(B)
Else
    Application.OnKey(B)          'Reset Application.OnKey so a recursive loop doesn't start. This works.
    Application.SendKeys(B)       'Send the string B (a letter). This works too.
    Application.OnKey(B), "'LetterPress B'" 'When you press B (not the key, the value in the string B, might be a or h or F or Q etc.) - start LetterPress with the string B as the argument.
End if
```

The last row doesn't work. It say's Can't find the macro. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: The call should be `"'LetterPress """ & B & """'"` because else it wouldn't know what B is (You want the call the macro with as parameter a string containing the contents of B). Also you don't need (and shouldn't add) parenthesis around B, it doesn't means what you think it does.

Comment: Thank you! I got the error "Argument not optional". I tried ```Application.OnKey , "'LetterPress """ & B & """'"``` I also tried ```Application.OnKey , "'LetterPress " & B & "'"```

Comment: You need the B, but not the parenthesis around it. Ie `Application.OnKey B` and not `Application.OnKey(B)`, and `Application.SendKeys B` and not  `Application.SendKeys(B)`. Parenthesis should only be used with `Call` keyword or when getting the returned value.

Comment: So the last line should be     `Application.OnKey B, "'LetterPress """ & B & """'"`

Comment: Thanks! The last line works now, but this starts a recursive loop too. How is that possible? If I remove the last line the code reset the ```OnKey``` command and then sends the key just like it should. The last line somehow triggers ```B``` again.

Comment: OK. I will delete my comment...

Comment: Since those functions are all more or less asynchronous, there is probably a race condition here where the OnKey is set again before the SendKeys is done. I would have thought that setting SendKeys second parameter to True (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys) would have solved the issue but it does not seems to have any impact.